# how often does nodebbpm scan for packages

Tags: nodebb

I'm writing a plugin for NodeBB. When I publish a new version via npm it seems to take the NodeBB Package Manager (nodebbpm) an arbitrary amount of time to pick it up.

At what interval does nodebbpm scan for packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's with SO cropping the beginning of my answer?

Hey @daniel-eiseinhardt -- the NodeBB package manager scans for changes in npm every 15 minutes: https://github.com/NodeBB/nodebb-package-manager/blob/master/index.js#L46

Hope that clears up any confusion over any delays!

If you want, you can trigger a manual refresh of a specific package by calling `PUT https://packages.nodebb.org/api/v1/plugins/nodebb-plugin-myplugin`